# Node and Angular form conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post

I have A front end Angular form, with Node reviving the data on the back end.

I have conditions on the from in the front end written in Angular, I would like have some extra conditions that would display with a new button to replace the submit button if the post was successful.

dose anyone know how I would do this ?  I was thinking something like ng-hide/show show text and button and hide form and submit button on form completion.

**Node Code**

```
var firstFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) { // may be redundant
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/api/data', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                // Get varibles from the post form
                var email_user = req.body.email;
                var first_name = req.body.fname;
                var last_name = req.body.lname;

                // res.send(email_user);
                res.send(first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' ' + email_user);

                //resolve when get the response
                resolve({
                    data_email: email_user,
                    data_first_name: first_name,
                    data_last_name: last_name
                });
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

**Angular code (view)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">First Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="Fname" placeholder="Enter first name"
           ng-model="formData.Fname"
           ng-required="true">
    <span ng-if="!myForm.Fname.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">Last Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="Lname" placeholder="Enter last name"
           ng-model="formData.Lname"
           ng-required="true">
    <span ng-if="!myForm.Lname.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">Email*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="email" placeholder="Enter valid E-mail"
           ng-model="formData.email"
           ng-required="true">
    <span ng-if="!myForm.email.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok " style="color: green" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info"
                ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">
            Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

**Angular code (controller)**

```
FirstModule.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.processForm = function (Fname, Lname, email) {
        var data = {
            fname: $scope.formData.Fname,
            lname: $scope.formData.Lname,
            email: $scope.formData.email
        };

//Call the services
//Change http://localhost:8080/api/data to /api/data when live
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/data', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";

        }, function (response) {
            $scope.formData = "Post Data Submitted Failed";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: You can either define a new route with a different view and the same controller and navigate to that one successful submission or you can set a variable on the scope when the data has been posted and have an `ng-if` in your view.

Comment: Hmm both could work but I think on successful sign up maybe a new view.